# How can I send a table as a parameter to stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, insert

I have a stored procedure in MySQL like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE addIns(IN insCode VARCHAR(21), IN insName VARCHAR(21), IN stat BIT(1))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO institution(institution.institution_code, institution.institution_name, institution.is_active) 
    VALUES (insCode, insName, stat);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I want like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE addIns(IN _institution)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO institution(institution.institution_code, institution.institution_name, institution.is_active)
    VALUES (_institution.institution_code, _institution.institution_name, _institution.is_active);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Because I want to use this stored procedure in Java Spring App.
How can I provide it?

My instutuion table is:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The sample code is not clear.  Also, my guess is that you don't really need this.  Instead, you have a problem with your data model.

Comment: I edited. I want to use this stored procedure in Java Spring. I send a post request as an instution and than I want to save to db from this stored procedure. @GordonLinoff

Comment: You cannot, because for parameters of functions or stored procedures,  only the data types mentioned [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) are allowed, and `TABLE` is not one of them.

Comment: You may send the name of the table as a parameter to SP. But for to use this parameter value as table name you must use dynamic SQL (prepared statement). *But I want like this* You must use `INSERT .. SELECT` instead of `INSERT .. VALUES`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE addIns(IN _institution)
BEGIN
    @sql := CONCAT( 'INSERT INTO institution (institution_code, institution_name, is_active) SELECT institution_code, institution_name, is_active FROM ' , _institution);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```